# Wie bezeichnet man Konstrukte wie "Wir sind Papst"?

Tags: single-word-request, phrase

Als im Jahr 2005 der frühere Kardinal Ratzinger zum Papst Benedikt XVI gewählt worden war, titelte die Bild-Zeitung am darauf folgenden Tag

> **Wir sind Papst!**

Die Wendung wurde analog zu "Wir sind Weltmeister!" gebildet und war bald sehr populär auch in anderen Abwandlungen.

Wäre es ein Wort, würde ich es eine *Wortschöpfung* nennen. Gibt es einen Fachbegriff dafür oder wie könnte man es kurz umschreiben?

Comment: Wie wärs mit Analogbildung?

Comment: Werbespot-Auswuchs? Wenn denn "Du bist Deutschland" die Geburt war. Ich glaube, "Wir sind Weltmeister" ist ein anderer Schnack, da stimmt ja formal alles.

Comment: @thei Ich denke gesucht wird ein Begriff, der auch schon auf "Wir sind Weltmeister" für sich alleine zutrifft.

Comment: Wie wär es mit: Zeitungen schreiben, was sie wollen.

Comment: Freie, und falsche, Übersetzung von *„habemus papam“*.

Comment: *Bild dir deine Sprache*

Comment: Nennt sich Delirium.

Comment: [`.oO( "lassen Sie uns durch, lassen Sie uns durch, wir sind Arzt." )`](http://www.lyricsbox.com/wir-sind-helden-lyrics-heldenzeit-ghnbp2c.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vorschlag: ein überzogenes "*Totum pro parte*" und damit eine ins Extreme gesteigerte **Synekdoche**.

In "Deutschland gewinnt auf 100m Gold" steht der Staat für den einzelnen Sportler ebenso wie in "Deutschland ist Weltmeister" (O-Ton 1954?) für die Fußball-Nationalmannschaft. In "Wir sind Weltmeister" ist das *totum* Staat durch das *totum* der Leser- / Zuhörerschaft ersetzt, die bei einer deutschlandweit erscheinenden, deutschsprachigen Zeitung oder einem deutschen Radio- oder Fernsehsender ebenfalls auf die Staatsangehörigkeit anspielt. "Wir sind Papst" treibt das in mehrfacher Hinsicht auf die Spitze:

- Der zugeschriebene Status dürfte wohl zu den denkbar exklusivsten gehören. Medaillengewinner gibt es üblicherweise mehrere auf einer Olympiade, Fußball-Weltmeisterschaften werden alle vier Jahre ausgetragen, aber das Papstamt wird nicht auf Zeit "vergeben" und kann auch nicht mit noch so viel Fleiß und Training "erkämpft" werden. Die Exklusivität steht einer Ausweitung auf das *totum* Staat bzw. Leserschaft an sich entgegen.
- Außerdem ist eine Papstwahl keinem internationalen Vergleich ähnlich, wie es bei Sportwettkämpfen (sei es mit einzelnen Mannschaften pro Nation, sei es mit mehreren untereinander konkurrierenden Teilnehmern der selben Nation) typisch ist. Dennoch ist die Nationalität des Gewählten von allgemeiner Bedeutung, aber eben nicht in einer Weise, wie sie für internationale Sportveranstaltungen typisch ist.

Der Satz "Wir sind Papst" könnte man daher vielleicht auch als Parodie eines "*Totum pro parte*" oder einer Synekdoche auffassen, wobei das eher den Effekt, nicht die Zielsetzung beschreiben dürfte.

Nachtrag: Siehe auch [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totum_pro_parte) und [gereimt.de](http://www.gereimt.de/fibel/stilmittel/?sm=113).

Comment: Sehr interessante Antwort, auch der Verweis auf den evtl. parodistischen Charakter. Willkommen!

Comment: Von welcher Bedeutung ist denn die Nationalität des Gewählten? Ist das eine besondere, katholische Sichtweise? Kommen nach kath. Sichtweise während der Amtszeit eines Deutschen Papstes Deutsche leichter in den Himmel? Wie vereinbart sich das damit, das fast alle Päpste bislang Italiener waren?

Comment: Genau! Aus dem griechischen ΣΥΝΕΚΔΟΧΗ.

Answer (score 3):

Ich halte das nicht für eine falsche Übersetzung von Habemus papam, sondern für eine bewusst eingesetzte Schlagzeilentechnik in witziger Analogie zu Fußballschlagzeilen wie "Wir sind Weltmeister". Die Schlagzeile hatte den gewünschten Effekt, sie fiel auf.

Answer (score 1):

Wie poke schon sagt, stammt *Wir sind Papst* wohl von einer falschen Übersetzung von *habemus papam* ab.

Ich glaube nicht, dass man jedes sprachliche Element für sich benennen und kategorisieren kann und muss. Daher würde ich hier den allgemeineren Begriff **Meme (oder [Mem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mem))** verwenden, da das eine Abwandlung einer anderen populären Wendung ist – egal, welche zuerst kam.

Comment: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Wir+sind+Weltmeister&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=0

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Wir+sind+Papst&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=0

Deine Vermutung ist falsch.

Comment: Tja... da sieht man mal, wieviel ich mit Fußball am Hut habe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ich bezeichne diese Aussage als Blödsinn... und die Konstruktion, zu der ich auch "Wie geht es uns denn heute" rechne, auch.

Comment: Die hat aber tatsächlich einen Namen in der Linguistik: Krankenschwester-wir